# Should i have different versions for a paragraph

Tags: html, css

Should i have different versions for the paragraph for a desktop view and a mobile view?
If on desktop, in the css mobile would be `display:none` and then vice versa for desktop

```
  <p className="Desktop">
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          <br />eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          <br />minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          <br />aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
       </p>
```

```
 <p className="mobile">
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br />
          consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          <br />
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore <br />
          et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          <br />
          minim veniam, quis nostrud <br />
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          <br />
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <br /> Duis aute irure dolor in
        </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about the flexibility.

First of all, you should use `class`, instead of `className`.

Then, there is no need to make two different paragraphs. It'd take too much time. Modern browsers define `p` element automatically 100% of the window. So there is no need to put `<br>` tag for each line.

In addition to this, if you want to make some changes for only mobile or desktop, you can use `@media` like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .custom-p{
        /*Here is the mobile codes*/
    }
}
```

But on your question, you don't even need this. Just write the paragraph.

Comment: what if i want the paragraph to be up to 50% of the window

Comment: Then you can add width: 50%; to .custom-p